# How the ranges changing?

Tags: python-3.7

```
def summaryRanges(self, nums):
    ranges, r = [], []
    for n in nums:
        if n-1 not in r:
            r = []
            ranges += r,
        r[1:] = n,
    return ['->'.join(map(str, r)) for r in ranges]
```

In this code, when the value of variable `r` is updated, the value of `ranges` gets updated irrespective of the condition satisfies or not.

When I printed the value of ranges as the value of `r` is updated the `ranges` was also updating with it even though there is no code for that outside the `if-block` .

The values of `ranges` I got for each iteration are -

[[0]]

[[0, 1]]

[[0, 2]]

[[0, 3]]

[[0, 3], [5]]

[[0, 3], [5, 6]]

[[0, 3], [5, 7]]

[[0, 3], [5, 7], [9]]

---

I wanted to know how is this value of range in `ranges` is changing automatically?